# Yii2 Attach behavior to Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to check for a cookie on `Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST`. What I did is overriding the `events` function from `Behavior` model and return a custom function `checkLanguage` on the event that I mentioned above. I am triggering `as beforeRequest` in my controller ( in first I tried in the `backend/config/main.php` but it seems that the `CheckIfLoggedIn` class can't be reached from there ) and the request goes e to the `public function events()` in the `CheckIfLoggedIn` class but doesn't go on to the `checkLanguage` function.
This is my `SiteController` behaviors:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index', 'language'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
            'as beforeRequest' => [
                'class' => 'backend\components\CheckIfLoggedIn'
            ]
        ];
    }
```

and `CheckIfLoggedIn.php` class:

```
<?php

namespace backend\components;

use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\web\Application;

class CheckIfLoggedIn extends Behavior
{
    public function events()
    {
        return [
            Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST => "changeLanguage"
        ];
    }

    public function changeLanguage()
    {
        if(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('lang')){
            \Yii::$app->language = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('lang');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is you are trying to attach an `Application` event at controller level inside the behavior whereas the documentation says you should use the `Application` config .

Make the following updates, remove the `events()` function from your class.

**`backend/components/CheckIfLoggedIn.php`**

```
namespace backend\components;
use yii\base\Behavior;

class CheckIfLoggedIn extends Behavior
{

    public function changeLanguage()
    {
        if(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('lang')){
            \Yii::$app->language = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('lang');
        }
    }
}
```

and add the following to the **`common/config`** or **`backend/config`** if you want it for `backend` only

```
'on '.yii\web\Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST => [
    'backend\components\CheckIfLoggedIn','changeLanguage'
] ,
```

remember to add it at the same level where `id` or `components` index is defined like this

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-backend' ,
    'on '.yii\web\Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST => [
        'backend\components\CheckIfLoggedIn','changeLanguage'
    ] ,
```

For the first try add a `die("hello world");` in the start of `changeLanguage` so you can confirm it is entering the function `changeLanguage`.

Hope it helps

Comment: How would you attach 2 or more behaviors to the same event?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal not following you 100% here , my answer **does not** show how to attach a behavior to an event, but a **handler** and that too via config, see docs for configuration setup https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-configurations#configuration-format , and the formats for the handler can bee seen here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events#attaching-event-handlers

Comment: I must have missed this part of the documentation. Thank you.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal no problem , you are welcome.